# Translating plasma units into SI units

Tags: electrons, frequency, dimensional-analysis, si-units, length

I am trying to compute the characteristic lengths and frequencies in a plasma, namely the electron plasma frequency and electron inertial length. From the NRL plasma formulary
$$\omega_{pe}\ [rad/s] = 5.64\times 10^4n_e^{1/2}$$
$$c/\omega_{pe}\ [cm] = 5.31\times 10^5/n_e^{1/2}$$
where $n_e$ is expressed in $cm^{-3}$. The factor $5.31\times 10^5$ is simply $c\ [cm/s]/5.64\times 10^4$.
Shouldn't the inertial length be in units of $cm/rad$ in the second formula? Then the actual physical length associated to the inertial length should be larger by a factor $2\pi$, so almost an order of magnitude larger. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Radians is dimensionless.

Comment: And yet $\omega_{pe}$ is not a frequency, but an angular frequency. If one were to measure plasma oscillations, the observed frequency would be $\omega_{pe}/2\pi$. My question is, shouldn't it be the same for the inertial length?